# Failure to run app after upgrading to polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.10 and reflectable: ^0.5.0

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I just upgraded to polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.10 with a dependecy_overrides of reflectable ^0.5.0.

I observed that whenever I upgraded a project with the above polymer and reflectable I get the following line in the output

```
Error on line 1, column 1 of https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/initialize: Invalid description: "test_package" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
```

Attempting to run my application fails with the following error

```
"P:\Program Files\Dart\dev\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat" serve web --port=56435
Loading source assets...
Loading web_components, reflectable and test/pub_serve transformers...
Serving epimss_polymer_app web on http://localhost:56435
Build error:
Transform WebComponents on epimss_polymer_app|web/index.html threw error: Class 'LibraryElementImpl' has no instance getter 'node'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'node'
Receiver: Instance of 'LibraryElementImpl'
Arguments: []
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 42                 Object._noSuchMethod
dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart 45                 Object.noSuchMethod
package:initialize/transformer.dart 240              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readAnnotations
package:initialize/transformer.dart 213              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 209              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 209              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 209              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 193              _BootstrapFileBuilder.run
package:initialize/transformer.dart 35               generateBootstrapFile
package:web_components/build/web_components.dart 32  generateWebComponentsBootstrap
package:web_components/build/web_components.dart 82  WebComponentsTransformer.apply.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1149                            _RootZone.runUnary
dart:async/future_impl.dart 551                      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
dart:async/future_impl.dart 637                      _Future._propagateToListeners
dart:async/future_impl.dart 424                      _Future._completeWithValue
dart:async/future_impl.dart 479                      _Future._asyncComplete.<fn>
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 41                _microtaskLoop
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 50                _startMicrotaskLoop
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 96             _runPendingImmediateCallback
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 149            _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage

dart:core                                            Object.noSuchMethod
package:initialize/transformer.dart 240              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readAnnotations
package:initialize/transformer.dart 213              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 209              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 209              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 209              _BootstrapFileBuilder._readLibraries
package:initialize/transformer.dart 193              _BootstrapFileBuilder.run
package:initialize/transformer.dart 35               generateBootstrapFile
package:web_components/build/web_components.dart 32  generateWebComponentsBootstrap
package:web_components/build/web_components.dart 82  WebComponentsTransformer.apply.<fn>.<fn>
[web] GET index.html => Could not find asset epimss_polymer_app|web/index.html.
[Info from Reflectable on epimss_polymer_app|ReflectableTransformed]:
Ignoring entry point my_project.web.index that does not include the class `Reflectable`.
Build completed with 1 errors.
```

Run pub cache repair but error remains.

Any suggestion as to how best to correct the issue please.

### EDIT 1

I have narrowed down the problem to be caused by either web_component, reflectable or polymer.

I created a new polymer-app with stage-hand and the application runs.

The new polymer-app pubspec.yaml is shown below:

```
name: 'ui_tester'
version: 0.0.1
description: A web app built using polymer.dart.
#author: Your Name <email@example.com>
#homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.1
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.10
  reflectable: ^0.5.0
#  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.9
#  reflectable: ^0.4.0
  web_components: ^0.12.1

transformers:
- web_components:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart
- $dart2js:
    $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart'
    minify: true
    commandLineOptions:
    - --trust-type-annotations
    - --trust-primitives
```

As soon as I change the dependencies to reflectable: 0.5.0 and polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.10 from 0.40 and 1.0.0.rc9 (commented lines) respectively the problem is reproduced consistently.

#### I am suggesting that there might a bug here.

I also noticed that stage-hand now uses

```
transformers:
- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart
```

instead of

```
transformers:
- reflectable:
    entry_points: web/index.dart
```

Are the codes similar in what they do?

Cheers

Comment: If the package versions were supposted to be compatible, you probably wouldn't need a dependency override. Why do you use the dependency override?

Comment: It is necessary to allow another 3rd-party package to work.

Comment: I guess you need to notify the maintainer of the 3rd party package to make it compatible with the new version of `reflectable`. I wasn't able yet to make the simplest Polymer application work with rc.10 yet anyway (I created some issues)

Comment: Good. Your attempts confirmed what was happening to me.

Answer (score 2):

**update**

Current workaround
- delete `.pub` directory
- run `pub upgrade` (error message still shown)
- limit the analyzer to version `0.27.1` (no `0.26.x` or `0.27.1+1` versions)

**orig**

I'm not sure if it's a pub issue as well because it's about a dev_dependency.
I created issue https://github.com/dart-lang/initialize/issues/43 in the initialize package to fix the `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. Looking forward to a solution ASAP as I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: The issue was updated. Deleting the `.pub` directory and running `pub upgrade` again is the current workaround. The error is still shown but the dependencies are updated properly.

Comment: What reflectable, polymer and polymer_elements versions did you get to work with analyzer: 0.27.1?

Comment: Polymer 1.0.0-rc.10, reflectable 0.5.1

Comment: After deleting the .pub directory in Webstorm and upgrading the project, no new .pub directory is generated. Is there a way to force this generation or I will have to recreate the project from scratch?

Comment: I guess you'll need to wait for the `pub` issue to be fixed. Does it cause problems that you don't have it? It still worked for me.

Comment: I keep getting the following errors in pub serve output | Build error:
Transform Reflectable on epimss_polymer_app|ReflectableTransformed threw error: The null object does not have a getter 'library'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'library'
Receiver: null PLUS other lines, none of which relates to my code directly.

Comment: What analyzer version do you have in `pubspec.lock`?

Comment: version: "0.27.1" in all pubspec.lock files.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what causes this error or how to work around.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.